# Show the parent forum in a topic with bbPress

Tags: bbpress, forum

In my forum based on bbPress, when I open a topic, the title shows only the title of the topic but not a link to the parent forum. That is annoying because the user has to go back with the browser and then select another topic.

Is there a way to add the parent forum as a link for a better user experience?

Comment: You'll have to ask bbPress's support team. Third-party plugin support (which includes bbPress) is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.